# Regex for parsing GitHub branch ref

Tags: javascript, regex, github-api

I'm really struggling using a single regex to parse a GitHub repo name and issue number out of a branch ref.  I see a way I could do it with 3 or 4 regexes and a decent amount of code, but I'd prefer 1 especially because I have a feeling something similar has been done.  I played around on http://regex101.com/#javascript for a while and can't seem to get it there.

This regex works for the first bunch of test strings: `/(\S+\/\S+)?#(\d+)/i`.
And this regex is my best stab at the second bunch, but doesn't work: `/(_|-|^)?(\d+)(_|-|$)?/`.  I would even be fine if the second one worked and then I could just run through both of them separately, but can't seem to make it happen.

Here is what I need matched.  Below are some test strings and after the comment, the desired matched groups.

```
'ex-owner/ex.repo#28'       // 1: ex-owner/ex.repo, 2: #28
'#28'                       // 1: null, 2: #28
'other>owner/repo#28stuff'  // 1: owner/repo, 2: #28
'other#39stuff'             // 1: null, 2: #28
'dont/match39me'            // no match

'123'                       // 1: null, 2: 123
'123myfeature'              // 1: null, 2: 123
'myfeature456'              // 1: null, 2: 456
'blah-123 ok'               // 1: null, 2: 123
'ok123-blah'                // 1: null, 2: 123
'ok123_blah'                // 1: null, 2: 123
'blah_123ok'                // 1: null, 2: 123
'not82valid'                // no match
'not.82.valid'              // no match
```

Really appreciate the help.  I wouldn't say I'm a newb to regex's since I've written a tokenizer for a simple language entirely using a single regex, but definitely not a pro.  Let me know if I'm going about this the wrong way too.

Cheers!

Comment: 'ex-owner/ex.repo#28'       // 1: owner/repo

This not possible because you cannot delete "ex." from the match "owner/ex.repo".

Comment: you're right, that was a typo on my part. fixed

Answer (score 0):

`/^(?:(\S+\/\S+)?#(\d+)\w*|(?:ok ?)?(\d+)[-_]?\w*?|\w*?[-_]?(\d+)(?: ?ok)?)$/`

For the first bunch it returns in 1 and 2, for the second bunch it returns the number in 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to match the way you want it:

```
/(?|([a-z-\.]+\/[a-z-\.]+)?(#\d+)|($)?(?:^|-|_)(\d+)|($)?(\d+)(?:$|-|_))/gmi
```

Check it out here: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vP0mC7/4)

Edit: Didn't see it was tagged with javascript, (?|) isn't supported in javascript, so here is a working solution (based on your examples):

```
/^(?:[a-z\.\/]+\d+[a-z\.\/]+)$|(?:([a-z\.-]+\/[a-z\.-]+)(?=#))?(#?\d+)/gmi
```

Where first part, `^(?:[a-z\.\/]+\d+[a-z\.\/]+)$`, "eats" invalid rows.

Where second part, `(?:([a-z\.-]+\/[a-z\.-]+)(?=#))`, matches `abc/def` followed by a `#`

And the last part, `(#?\d+)`, matches one or zero `#` followed by one or more digits.

Check it out here: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vP0mC7/6)